# Discord bot isn't sending the else part of an if not, else statement?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, discord, discord.py, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to create a leveling section to my bot however it isn't reading the else part in this code as it isn't send the embeded message. There is no error/traceback.
Code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
            member = ctx.author if not member else member
            member_id = str(member.id)
            guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)

            user = await self.bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2", member_id, guild_id)

            if not user:
                await ctx.send(f"{member} doesn't have a level.")
            else:
                embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.colour, timestamp=ctx.message_created_at)

                embed.set_author(name=f"Level - {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

                embed.add_field(name="Level", value=user[0]['lvl'])
                embed.add_field(name="XP", value=user[0]['xp'])

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious issues use `print()` to see where it stops. I believe it would end at `embed.set_author` but that is dependent on what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line `embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.colour, timestamp=ctx.message_created_at)`
correct is `embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)`
see [Message.created_at](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at)
Your code should then look like this:

```
@commands.command()
async def level(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    member_id = str(member.id)
    guild_id = str(ctx.guild.id)

    user = await self.bot.pg_con.fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND guild_id = $2", member_id, guild_id)

    if not user:
        await ctx.send(f"{member} doesn't have a level.")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=member.colour, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.set_author(name=f"Level - {member}", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name="Level", value=user[0]['lvl'])
        embed.add_field(name="XP", value=user[0]['xp'])

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```